# To send more than 256 byte data via push notification

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

I am new in iPhone,I tried to send data up to 256 byte but i want to know how to send more than 256 byte data of image data through push notification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No You can't.**

The maximum size allowed for a notification payload is 256 bytes; Apple Push Notification Service refuses any notification that exceeds this limit.

And You have to send JSON Object in Payload.

See [Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html)

Comment: Is it possible to send any image through push notificaton?

Comment: NO, but you can send image name or a URL from which the image can be downloaded within the app. but remember your payload size not excluding 256.

Comment: thanks viruss mca but i want to ask that can i send image as notification alert

Comment: No you can't send image as notification alert.\

Comment: How wan i get size of payload?

Comment: @Optimistic: I guess 1 character = 1 byte.

Comment: For which platform you are sending it to apns??

Comment: Sorry i didn't get you.??

Comment: I mean what are you using for send to server, PHP or ASP.net?

Comment: can you check it at asp.net side., i have no knowledge of .net side.

Comment: If you also dont know , you can possible to your team who developed it.

Comment: @Virussmca: ok , i'll ask them..Thnks.

Comment: @Virussmca: one more question related to notification, is i have to add new device every time for get push? or i can use old certificates ?

Comment: Yes you have to add new device at dev portal, you can't use old certificate to get pushnotification in new added device.

Comment: @Optimistic: it is very easy, from xcode organizer, when you attech new device it will ask to use as devlopment, just select, and it will automatically add it to app dev portal with given account.

Comment: @Virussmca: oh great, i haven't try this,Thnks again.

Answer (score 2):

The Notification Payload

Each push notification includes a payload. The payload contains information about how the system should alert the user as well as any custom data you provide. The maximum size allowed for a notification payload is 256 bytes; Apple Push Notification Service refuses any notification that exceeds this limit.

In this 236 is for alert message and 20 bytes is structure of message